# Symfony 2: Upload file and save as blob

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, blob

I'm trying to save images in database with forms and Doctrine. In my entity, I've done this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="blob", nullable=true)
 */
private $photo;

private $file;


/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    $this->setPhoto(file_get_contents($this->getFile()));
}
```

And I've also added this in my form type:

```
->add('file', 'file')
```

But I'm getting this error when I upload a file:

> Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile'
>   is not allowed

Comment: Please can someone help me ? I succeed to fix the serialization error adding 'mapped' => false to my file field but with that I can't upload even with @tttony answer...

Answer (score 9):

You have to save the image file content as binary

```
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    //$strm = fopen($this->file,'rb');
    $strm = fopen($this->file->getRealPath(),'rb');
    $this->setPhoto(stream_get_contents($strm));
}
```

[`UploadedFile`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) is a class that extends [`File`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html) that extends [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo)

`SplFileInfo` has the function [`getRealPath()`](http://php.net/manual/es/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php) that returns the path of the temp filename.

This is just in case that you don't want to upload the file to the server, to do that [follow these steps](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#basic-setup).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I tried and it seems not to work

Comment: Actually, `$this->file` is an instance of `UploadedFile`

Comment: To fix my serialization error I added `'mapped' => false` to my field and I succeed once to upload my image but it didn't work again...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when Symfony uploads a file it assigns the property that the file is uploaded to an object of type `UploadedFile`.

So `$file` is of type `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile.`

The error message you are getting is telling you that you cannot store an object of that type like that - and really you don't want to do that anyway, you want to pass the file name with path to `file_get_contents()`.

So all you need to do to fix this is to access the location of the file from the object like so:

`$this->setPhoto(file_get_contents($this->getFile()->getPathname()));`

Note the call to `getPathname()` added to the end of the chain.

Also, I would definitely keep `file_get_contents()` because the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) states that:

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.